# Add initially missing collection items via binding

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, observablecollection, default-value

Given:

```
class StringRecord : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Key   { get; set; } // real INPC implementation is omitted
    public string Value { get; set; } // real INPC implementation is omitted
    ...
}

class Container
{
    public ObservableKeyedCollection<string, StringRecord> Params { get; set; }
    ...
{
```

The `ObservableKeyedCollection` is [the one found here](http://geekswithblogs.net/NewThingsILearned/archive/2010/01/12/make-keyedcollectionlttkey-titemgt-to-work-properly-with-wpf-data-binding.aspx).

A TextBox is bound to one of the collection items (DataContext is inherited):

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Params[APN_HOST].Value}"/>
```

When I manually add the "APN_HOST" item to the collection, the binding works as expected.

Now, where I'm stuck: I want to be able to edit an empty collection that way, i.e.,

> If there's no item in the collection with the specified key, and user types some text to the textbox, it would result in a new item added to the collection with the corresponding key.

I tried to implement some kind of "default if not found" semantics in the collection, but it resulted in all the textboxes being bound to the same default instance of `StringRecord`, sharing a single value :)

Feels like I'm overlooking something really obvious here.

Comment: Have you tried [BindingBase.FallbackValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.fallbackvalue) or [BindingBase.TargetNullValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.targetnullvalue)?

Comment: @LPL Yeah, it shows up in the textbox expectedly and correctly, but when edited, new item still doesn't get added to the collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that was a really tough one!

What I've done is:

1) Extended `ObservableKeyedCollection` with

```
public class ObservableKeyedCollection<TKey, TItem> : KeyedCollection<TKey, TItem>, INotifyCollectionChanged
{
    ...
    Func<TKey,TItem> m_newItemDelegate;

    public ObservableKeyedCollection(Func<TItem, TKey> getKeyForItemDelegate, Func<TKey, TItem> newItemDelegate = null)
        : base()
    {
        ...
        m_newItemDelegate = newItemDelegate;
    }

    public new TItem this[TKey key]
    {
        get
        {
            if (m_newItemDelegate != null && !Contains(key))
            {
                TItem i = m_newItemDelegate(key);
                var i_as_inpc = i as INotifyPropertyChanged;
                if (i_as_inpc != null)
                    i_as_inpc.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(AddItemOnChangeHandler);
                else
                    Add(i);
                return i;
            }
            return base[key];
        }
        set
        {
            if (Contains(key)) Remove(key);
            Add(value);
        }
    }

    private void AddItemOnChangeHandler(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        (sender as INotifyPropertyChanged).PropertyChanged -= AddItemOnChangeHandler;
        Add((TItem)sender);
    }
```

- Despite that the indexer is declared as `new`, binding engine correctly resolves it.
- If the new-item-delegate is provided, we utilise it for obtaining some default item instance for a missing key. This new item is not immediately added to the collection, because it could violate the requirement of only adding values after user has actually edited them. Instead,
- If the item implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, we hook to its `PropertyChanged` event, add the item to the collection from the handler and immediately unsubscribe from `PropertyChanged`.

This alone would be enough, but... for some strange reason, nested property notifications doesn't fire!

2) Rewritten the binding as follows:

```
<TextBox DataContext="{Binding Params[APN_HOST]}" Text="{Binding Value}" />
```

Now it fires, triggering the above mechanism!

**EDIT.** After some discussion conducted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10966329/inotifypropertychanged-doesnt-fire-when-declared-in-certain-syntax/), I now see that the second modification was inevitable part of the solution, because of the defaulting behaviour. There's simply no other possibility to determine which instance has been changed.